# How to typecheck angular component template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom component that takes two inputs. Using TypeScript, I want to enforce that the second input can only be provided if the first input is also provided.

e.g.:

```
export class MyTestClass implements Test{
  @Input() dog?: string;
  @Input() treat?: string; // Should only be able to exist if dog also exists
}
```

I have tried creating a generic interface for the component to implement, like so:

```
interface Test<Dog extends string | undefined = string> {
  dog?: Dog;
  treat?: Dog extends string ? string : undefined
}
```

But unfortunately, typescript does not complain when I try to use the template the wrong way:

```
<my-test-class [treat]="'not type-checked'">
</my-test-class>
```

Is there any way to enforce this relationship between inputs in Angular (hopefully during compile-time and not at run-time)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`selector`](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector) of the [`@Component`](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) decorator:

```js
@Component({
 template: "...",
 style: "...",
 selector: `
  app-my-component[dog],
  app-my-component[dog][treat],
  app-my-component:not([treat])
 `
})
class MyComponent { }
```

I'm using `,` for or operations, `[attr]` to select on the presence of attributes, and the `:not` pseudo-selector to exclude the case were just `treat` is present.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't those brackets mean that both dog and treat must be provided for the component to be rendered?

If so, I would like for the component to be able to be rendered even if the dog isn't provided, or if the dog is provided and the treat isn't.

Comment: I overlooked that and edited my answer to expand the query so that it matches exactly what you look for: either none, or both given. The `,` is the or operator

Comment: Ah, still misunderstood haha! But ok, same difference, now it shows how to do none, dog, or dog and treat, but not just treat!

Comment: This actually simplifies to just the 1st and 3rd query, but I think it's informative to show that the and operator works like in CSS :)

Comment: This works for this simple case. However, if I have many optional inputs for this component, do I have to add all the possible combinations of attributes for the selector?

Comment: It's starting to smell like maybe there's a better design solution for your problem, rather than to bind to so many properties with such intricate requirements for what' starting to feel like schema validation ;p

Comment: Maybe you ought to split some of this off into their own subcomponents. and validate there, or split it off into other `Directive`s/`Resolver`s/`Guard`s. And from experience, I think `ng build` does detect more of these at compile time, so maybe there's a compiler option you can turn on during serve as well.

Comment: A few optional inputs where one of them is dependent on another is very easy to express with typescript, and wouldn't really call it intricate. I find it surprising that I'm bound to attribute selectors for template type checking. Nevertheless, thanks for your suggestion and your help so far. I'll look into that.